# "Simple"? ISC DHCP set-up using POE switch for cctv cameras

Tags: networking, dhcp

I want to use a headless ubuntu server setup on a SBC to connect to and record from cameras through a POE switch only.. no router.

Can an ISC DHCP installation be used for this?  (Or is there a better way?)  I am unclear on how it can be made to work in this scenario.  Beginning questions.. if it can be done..

1. How to ssh into the SBC when trying to connect to it through the switch.. will it have the x.x.x.1 address already assigned to itself?

How to deal with DNS settings since this will not be connected to the internet?

What is the longest I can/should set a lease time for, for the cameras?

All the tutorials and youtube videos I have found so far seem to deal with computers still connected to a router and the internet.  Are there any good examples of something similar to my setup?

Thank you

Comment: Just set cameras and the SBC to static addresses. That way you don't have to deal with finding cameras on the network. DNS shouldnt play any role at all if you want cameras and sbc to talk to each other on LAN only

Comment: For a headless system, how does that process work?... ..for example.. a switch with a camera, the SBC.. and temporarily a laptop (to ssh into the SBC)..  is the SBC automatically set up and findable by the laptop?  ...That would mean the SBC automatically assigns and IP to the laptop?  Or would they both have to be set up statically in the SBC by mac ID?  Is ISC, or dnsmasq a better approach?